# Error response while performing WebAPI /CheckConnection request

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently working on a Chrome Plugin. These uses a WebAPI to Authenticate the user. That returns a access_token and that is saved as a cookie.

I need to call the /CheckConnection value to check if the token is still aviable but that process won't get going.
I allways get an error result.

```
var token = getCookie("access_token");
var header={};
header.Authorization="bearer "+token;
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://api.youcan.science/api/values/CheckConnection",
    "Authorization": 'bearer ' + token,
    header: header,
    data: {
        'access_token':token
    }
}).done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
}).fail(function (e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

For testing you may use this token:

```
var token = "dP4aCmK_27I69X02Jc7JoY6mGVHP3LddPXpnA0Jg4MH5H_-UOAEh14YUFBxfS_S2DwzErIFGfC61HCGlQASTMUkK96OVWBhxAE8Pm0E6JTFoSpkac9UaAFAhvoOkuS4G4vFoKNV1zmEajPdWrNRLudcTgYs1JVZFSYai4ZJ6ug82SDsdKSo5FVOklnw_ReWCDbLrekED0H7IG5feKQyy5IZ9HDGyN5Qxs9kjbTEd50J2Su1_kkJJRfXDWxL05Rjc-GGZGQLtZ7e6vBA57DxDyUu1ZwF0HxA7Rfao7jZFTMR35mRolnrGvwSemJRTW0cwd0laThz5UnHVjhSYhfJqapfOxlZYyakj4MIjafp2UzJKB-HsQpI8_LagjUFnwulAF6CXNKIuXjC5WE8O_hMvKm4GyZ3aQKc_8-sAuAiSw0XdlLhPdY-Yvwx5nlSI2UlAnSkSj7XB4WyN-M2_AGX5rGHrjHh1w1QP4DwOQD05bII"
```

Comment: It's not a plugin, it's an extension. Extensions define site permissions in manifest.json, see the documentation.

Comment: Yes - i meaned that